# There is the distortion of pixel when i see in play mode in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, sprite-sheet

My all sprites are in the 16x16 pixel. This same thing is happening in the phone also.when ever I move the player. [image]

Comment: Hi Vivek, welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect this was down voted because it's not really a question; instead it reads more like an internal bug report with vague repro steps. See https://stackoverflow.com/help for more detail on how to ask a question that others will find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Had to set camera's "Clear flags" option to "solid color", and problem solved :)